# How to overlay a structure / union from the C language with data in Flutter / Dart (data transfer via Bluetooth)

Tags: c, flutter, dart, unions

I am passing data byte by byte from a C application. If the receiving application is also in the C language, then the problem is solved simply - you need to declare the same structure / union and write data there. But in Dart there is no such possibility. You can, of course, allocate bytes manually by creating a helper class, but the structure can be complex and difficult to do. How to transfer a complex structure from a C application to a Dart / Flutter application via Bluetooth?

```
typedef struct _command_packet
{
unsigned char command;
unsigned char current_temperature;
unsigned char processor_temperature;
unsigned char heater_temperature;
unsigned char software_version;
unsigned char LEDs;
unsigned char water_level;
unsigned char Recipe_number;
unsigned char target_temperature;
unsigned char step_number; 
unsigned char after_heating_temperature;
unsigned char after_heating_time;
unsigned char reserved_2;
char Coffee_Temperature_Correction;
unsigned short int Coffee_Cups_Number;
unsigned short int water_sensor_raw_data;
} __command_packet;

#define COMMAND_PACKET_LENGTH 18

typedef union _command_packet_charint
{
   __command_packet command_packet;
   unsigned char command_packet_char[COMMAND_PACKET_LENGTH];
} command_packet_charint;
```

Comment: Best is to serialize it. Send in text format as JSON or XML

Comment: Yes, it works, but
1. This method greatly increases the amount of transmitted data
2. In my case it is not possible to change the sending application